# How to adjust this html (or CSS) files to auto-break this long Mathjax equation?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, line-breaks, mathjax

I have this complete [webpage](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q8Be246J6o2SfYm_rDVzh9AHGROWdt_3) in which there is a long equation:

```
<div class="exercise">
<p class="math">Let \(S = \{0, 1\}^2\). This is the set of outcomes when a coin is tossed twice (0 denotes tails and 1 denotes heads). Give \(\mathscr{P}(S)\) in list form.</p>

<details>
<summary>Answer:</summary>
<p class="proof">\(\{\emptyset, \{00\}, \{01\}, \{10\}, \{11\}, \{00, 01\}, \{00, 10\}, \{00, 11\}, \{01, 10\}, \{01, 11\}, \{10, 11\}, \{00, 01, 10\}, \{00, 01, 11\}, \{00, 10, 11\}, \{01, 10, 11\}, \{00, 01, 10, 11\}\}\)</p>
</details>
</div>
```

[image]

Because the equation is so long that the output PDF has very small font size. Here is the output PDF:

[image]

Could you please elaborate on how to adjust this html (or CSS) files to auto-break this long Mathjax equation?

---

**Update:**

Here is the CSS for `exercise`.

```
div.exercise{
    border: dashed 1px rgb(200, 200, 100);
    background: rgb(240, 240, 220);
    counter-increment: exerciseCount;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Here is the CSS for `math`.

```
p.math, p.sim, p.stat, p.art{
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Here is the CSS for `proof`.

```
p.proof{
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You can use css property `word-break: break-all;` to let the long string break to fit the container. Please refer [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: @ShawnXiao I've just tried your suggestion, but to no avail :((

Comment: Could you please post the html code of the long Mathjax?

Comment: We should also need the css codes of class `proof`, `math` and `exercise`.

Comment: Hi @ShawnXiao added.

Comment: Your problem is the long Mathjax can break correctly in HTML, but after exported to PDF, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ShawnXiao It's sad to hear that :(( I intend to save many such html as PDF by Google Chrome. The small font size is very annoying.